# satisfying an equality in an infinite sum

Tags: calculus, summation

In a text I am reading, it is mentioned that using the chain rule in reverse, the equality can be satisfied.
Unfortunately, I am unable to achieve this.
$$\frac{1}{p}\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}ln\left | f'\left ( x_{i} \right ) \right |=\frac{1}{p}ln\left | \left ( f^{p} \right )'\left ( x_{0} \right ) \right |$$

I should add that $f^{p}$ is a p-iteration of the function f. I.e., a composition of a function p times.
Any help to bring me through is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are $x_0$, $x_1$, ..., $x_{p-1}$? Are they any real numbers or is there some kind of relation between them?

Comment: They're just points along a real number line.@AugSB
The prime denotes derivatives with respect the the points and the superscript p denotes a function f of a function f, p times.

Comment: I think that in this problem $x_1:=f(x_0), x_2:=f(x_1),\dots$.

Comment: Yes, it is. This is the definition of a discrete map.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that $x_{i}=f(x_{i-1})$ and, hence, $x_{i}=f^{i}(x_0)$.

First, note that
$$\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\ln | f'( x_{i} ) | =  \ln\left(\prod_{i=0}^{p-1} | f'( x_{i} ) |\right),$$
so it is enough to showthat
$$\prod_{i=0}^{p-1} | f' ( x_{i} ) | = | ( f^{p}  )' ( x_{0} ) |.$$

You can show this by induction:
$$ p=1 \implies | f'( x_{0} ) | = | ( f^{1} )'( x_{0} ) |.$$
$$ p=2 \implies | f'( x_{0} ) |\cdot | f'( x_{1} ) | = | f'(f(x_0))\cdot f'(x_0)  | = | ( f^{2} )'( x_{0} ) |.$$
So, assuming it is true up to $p-1$, let's show it for $p$:
$$\prod_{i=0}^{p-1} | f' ( x_{i} ) | = | f' ( x_{p-1} ) |\cdot \prod_{i=0}^{p-2} | f' ( x_{i} ) | = | f' ( x_{p-1} ) |\cdot | ( f^{p-1}  )' ( x_{0} ) | \\
 = | f' ( f^{p-1}(x_0) )\cdot ( f^{p-1}  )' ( x_{0} ) | = | ( f^{p}  )' ( x_{0} ) |.$$